# MultiTermVectors in Elasticsearch Java

Tags: java, python, elasticsearch

I am using the following function to get the term vector for some set of IDs.

```
public static void builtTermVectorRequest(Client client, String index, Map<String, String> postIDs) {
    TermVectorsRequest termVectorsRequest = new TermVectorsRequest();
    termVectorsRequest.index(index).type("post");
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : postIDs.entrySet()) {
      String currentPostId = entry.getKey();
      String currentParentID = entry.getValue();
      termVectorsRequest
              .id(currentPostId)
              .parent(currentParentID)
              .termStatistics(true)
              .selectedFields("content");
    }

    MultiTermVectorsRequestBuilder mtbuilder = client.prepareMultiTermVectors();
    mtbuilder.add(termVectorsRequest);

    MultiTermVectorsResponse response = mtbuilder.execute().actionGet();
    XContentBuilder builder;
    try {
      builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject();
      response.toXContent(builder, ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS);
      builder.endObject();
      System.out.println(builder.prettyPrint().string());
    } catch (IOException e) {}
  }
```

Here I have some document IDs along with their parent IDs as the documents are child documents.

I get that the documents were not found even when they exist.

To confirm I tried the same thing in Python using:

```
body = dict(docs=map(lambda x:
                     {
                         "fields": ["content"],
                         "_id": x["_id"],
                         "_routing": x["_routing"],
                         "term_statistics": "true"
                     }, result["hits"]["hits"]))

es_client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch([{'host': '192.168.111.12', 'port': 9200}])

all_term_vectors = es_client.mtermvectors(
    index="prf_test",
    doc_type="post",
    body=body
)
```

and I get results back.

What is wrong with the Java code?

Comment: looks like some `routing` issue is `x["_routing"]` same as ParentId if so  could you explicitly try `.routing(currentParentID)` ?

Comment: @keety Sorry for not following up. I was getting the same issue even after that I tried with some more combinations and finally got it to work. You can view my answer.

Comment: cool nice to know thanks

Answer (score 3):

I tried out more combinations on how to use `TermVectorsRequest` with `MultiTermVectorsRequestBuilder` and finally came to the following solution which works:

```
/**
 * Prints term-vectors for child documents given their parent ids
 *
 * @param client    Es client
 * @param index     Index name
 * @param postIDs   Map of child document ID to its _parent/_routing ID
 */
public static void builtTermVectorRequest(Client client, String index, Map<String, String> postIDs) {
  /**
   * Initialize the MultiTermVectorsRequestBuilder first
   */
  MultiTermVectorsRequestBuilder multiTermVectorsRequestBuilder = client.prepareMultiTermVectors();

  /**
   * For every document ID, create a different TermVectorsRequest and 
   * add it to the MultiTermVectorsRequestBuilder created above
   */
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : postIDs.entrySet()) {
    String currentPostId = entry.getKey();
    String currentRoutingID = entry.getValue();
    TermVectorsRequest termVectorsRequest = new TermVectorsRequest()
            .index(index)
            .type("doc_type")
            .id(currentPostId)
            .parent(currentRoutingID) // You can use .routing(currentRoutingID) also
            .selectedFields("some_field")
            .termStatistics(true);
    multiTermVectorsRequestBuilder.add(termVectorsRequest);
  }

  /**
   * Finally execute the MultiTermVectorsRequestBuilder
   */
  MultiTermVectorsResponse response = multiTermVectorsRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();

  XContentBuilder builder;
  try {
    builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject();
    response.toXContent(builder, ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS);
    builder.endObject();
    System.out.println(builder.prettyPrint().string());
  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
}
```